# How to Ctrl-Z in Perl script

Tags: perl, unix

I am writing a Perl script and I need to execute Unix <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on the script.
How can I do it in Perl ?

thanks.

Comment: Do you want to send an already-running process to the background, or start it backgrounded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From perl you can send signals to processes with the function kill, which has the same name as the Unix command line tool that does the same thing. The equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is running

> kill -SIGTSTP pid

you need to find out what numeric value your TSTP signal has on your system. You would do this by running

> kill -l TSTP

on the command line. Let's say this returns 20

Then in your Perl script you would add

> kill 20 => $$;

which will send the TSTP signal to the currently running process id ($$)

**Update:**
as described by daxim, you can skip the 'kill -l' part and provide the name of the signal directly:

```
kill 'TSTP' => $$;
```

Comment: Too complicated. Just `kill 'TSTP' …`, `kill 'HUP' …` etc. See http://p3rl.org/ipc

Comment: @daxim Thank you, you are right about the syntax, though I really wouldn't point perlipc as gentle help for people who don't know about signals

Comment: I really don't like the use of `=>` here, and feel that a comma would be cleaner and clearer. Substituting `=>` for `,` is a syntax sugar invented for hashes, and feels like abuse in situations like this.

Answer (score -2):

In bash <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> stops the current job and puts it in background with %JobId you can return to this job. I'm not sure what you mean since I thought <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> is caught by bash..

Comment: I want the script to send the bash to put a specific job in the background.