# Suspending a running shell command in a Perl script

Tags: perl, multiprocessing, signals

I have a Perl script that executes a shell command as follows

```
system("command");
```

I need to suspend the execution of that command for a certain amount of time then resume it again from the script itself. I tried to do the following

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$pid = fork();
if( $pid == 0 ) {
   print "This is child process\n";
   exec('command') or die($!);
   print "Child process is exiting\n";
   exit 0;
}

print "This is parent process and child ID is $pid\n";
kill 'TSTP',$pid;  
sleep 60;
kill 'CONT',$pid;
while (wait() != -1) {}
print "Parent process is exiting\n";
exit 0;
```

But this is the output I get

```
This is child process
Output of command
This is parent process and child ID is 15606
Parent process is exiting
```

The parent process suspends the child process after the command finsh execution which is not what I need.
I checked the answer for that question also

> [How to Ctrl-Z in Perl script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394391/how-to-ctrl-z-in-perl-script/3394653)

but I am not sure how to use

```
kill 'TSTP' => $$;
```

to suspend the running command and then resume it again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221093/discussion-on-question-by-merolla-suspending-a-running-shell-command-in-a-perl-s).